# Error occurs in Pretraining KoBERT using MLM

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, bert-language-model, transformer-model

```
text = ""
inputs = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt') #inputs = tokenizer.encode(text, return_tensors='pt')

print(inputs)

rand = torch.rand(inputs.input_ids.shape)

mask_arr = (rand < 0.15) * (inputs.input_ids != 2) * (inputs.input_ids != 3) * (inputs.input_ids != 0)

selection = torch.flatten((mask_arr[0]).nonzero())

import numpy as np

selection_val = np.random.random(len(selection)) 

mask_selection = selection[np.where(selection_val >= 0.2)[0]] 
random_selection = selection[np.where(selection_val < 0.1)[0]]

print(random_selection) # tensor([ 30,  95, 143])
print(mask_selection)

inputs.input_ids[0, mask_selection] = 103
inputs.input_ids[0, random_selection] = torch.randint(0, 30522, size = random_selection.shape)

class MeditationsDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, encodings):
        self.encodings = encodings
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return {key: torch.tensor(val[idx]) for key, val in self.encodings.items()}
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.encodings.input_ids)

from transformers import TrainingArguments
from transformers import Trainer

dataset = MeditationsDataset(inputs)


args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='result', 
    per_device_train_batch_size=16, 
    num_train_epochs=2 
)

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model, 
    args=args, 
    train_dataset=dataset 
)

trainer.train()
```

error code:

```
RuntimeError Traceback (most recent call last) in <cell line: 25>() 23 ) 24 ---> 25 trainer = Trainer( 26 model=model, 27 args=args,

5 frames /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/cuda/random.py in cb() 109 for i in range(device_count()): 110 default_generator = torch.cuda.default_generators[i] --> 111 default_generator.manual_seed(seed) 112 113 _lazy_call(cb, seed_all=True)
```

```
RuntimeError: CUDA error: device-side assert triggered CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call, so the stacktrace below might be incorrect. For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1. Compile with TORCH_USE_CUDA_DSA to enable device-side assertions.
```

What was wrong?

I found that device-side assert triggered CUDA kernel errors are triggered by unappropriate class index number, but I can't know where I can specify that.